# Structural Analysis Package

Tags: stanli

I am trying to add a label "100 lb/in" on both of the load distributions. Every time I attempted it, the labels pop up in places I did not intend them to be. I want them to be on top for the horizontal beam and to the right for the vertical beam. Furthermore, I am trying to add "A" at the bottom of the horizontal beam and "B" to the vertical one to the left. How can I accomplish this. Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{stanli}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\scaling{.1};
\point{a}{0}{50};
\point{b}{28}{50};
\point{c}{28}{0};
\support{3}{a}[-90];
\support{3}{c};
\beam{4}{a}{b}[0][1];
\beam{4}{b}{c}[1][0];
\hinge{2}{b}[a][c][0];
\lineload{2}{a}{b} [0.75][0.75][.125];
\lineload{1}{b}{c} [0.75][0.75][.0055];
\dimensioning{1}{a}{b}{-1}[$28$ in];
\dimensioning{2}{c}{b}{-1}[$50$ in];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this the `stanli` package you're using? If yes, please that tag instead of (or in addition to) the much more general `tikz-pgf` tag. And doesn't hurt if you make a complete example (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`) :) Then those who want to test can just copy-paste the entire code without making any modifications at all.

Comment: yes that makes sense. i did as you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `stanli` package, you can insert a text with `\notation` command. For details you can look package documentation on CTAN.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{stanli}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\scaling{.1};
\point{a}{0}{50};
\point{b}{28}{50};
\point{c}{28}{0};
\point{d}{14}{60};
\point{e}{40}{25};
\point{A}{12}{43};
\point{B}{22}{25};
\support{3}{a}[-90];
\support{3}{c};
\beam{4}{a}{b}[0][1];
\beam{4}{b}{c}[1][0];
\hinge{2}{b}[a][c][0];
\lineload{2}{a}{b} [0.75][0.75][.125];
\lineload{1}{b}{c} [0.75][0.75][.0055];
\dimensioning{1}{a}{b}{-1}[$28$ in];
\dimensioning{2}{c}{b}{-1}[$50$ in];
\notation {1}{d}{ 100 lb/in }[ above ];
\notation {1}{e}{ 100 lb/in }[ right ];
\notation {1}{A}{ A };
\notation {1}{B}{ B };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to add hatch to the distributed lad, control colors and stuff for lines and various elements in Stanli?

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation of the Stanli package available at ctan.org.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568148/internalforces-command-in-stanli-package